# How to clone an object in the same position as the GameObject - Solved

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I´m new to Unity and I´m trying to clone the sphere in the same position as the `GameObject`. The `GameObject` is moving and I want it to clone the sphere every time it moves to mark the place where it started the movement.

I´m currently using `Instantiate (sphere, transform.position);` in the script of the `GameObject`, but I´m getting the error message

> " error CS1503: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'UnityEngine.Vector3'
> to 'UnityEngine.Transform'"

Is there anything I can do to fix this?
(The `GameObject` is called sphere so that's not the problem)

Comment: try `Instantiate(sphere, transform)` instead - you are trying to supply a vector3 (the position property) when the method requires a `Transform` object. Bear in mind this makes the original object a parent of the new one - that may not be what you want. If you don't want the original to be a parent, try `Instantiate(sphere, transform.position, transform.rotation)` - to be fair I don't really know Unity that well so try both

Comment: The compiler is telling you that you are passing the wrong type to the Instantiate method.  You need to pass it a Transform.  And, you have one.  Just remove the ".position".

Comment: Check docs here to see all the methods and overloads available:

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html

Comment: Thanks a lot, I´m not getting an error message anymore

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting is **"Argument 2: cannot convert from 'UnityEngine.Vector3' to 'UnityEngine.Transform'"**

**Argument 2** tells you the problem is with the second argument

**cannot convert from 'UnityEngine.Vector3' to 'UnityEngine.Transform** tells you you're supplying `Vector3` to the argument when it expects to get a `Transform`.

Maybe the "cannot convert from" part was confusing to you? Basically C# is telling you that it expects `Transform`, it is getting `Vector3` and it doesn't know what to do with it. If it for example expected a `float` it got an `int` then it wouldn't complain because *it knows how to convert between the two*.

The solution is simply to use `Instantiate (sphere, transform);`

Answer (score 0):

You're receiving this error because the second argument needs to be a Transform component, not a Vector3.

For more information about the excepted values you can check [Unity Docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html).

There is two ways to fix your code:

1. The first is by passing the Transform object component to the object:
    *(You're only supplying transform.position, which is a Vector3)*

```cs
//Instantiate(theObject, theTransform);
Instantiate(sphere, transform);
```

2. You provide another Vector3 as the rotation that you like:

```cs
//Instantiate(theObject, thePosition, theRotation);
Instantiate(sphere, transform.position, transform.rotation);
```